# How to run laravel mix steps sequentially?

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-mix

How would you make sure a step is completed before executing another set of mix steps?

I want to copy a dynamically generated file to the resources folder, before compiling the `.scss` files. However, the steps seem to run in parallel or the order doesn't seem to be guaranteed.

I want the following script,

```
mix.copy('generated.scss', 'resources/assets/sass/to-be-imported.scss');
```

to run before the following...

```
mix
.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.version();
```

Comment: Why don't you import the `generated.scss` in your `app.scss` directly?

Comment: @Jerodev The `generated.scss` is generated during the build time, depending on the environment variables present..

Comment: But what script builds this `generated.scss`? Can it be used as a trigger?

Comment: The file is supposed to be generated when the `npm run dev` command is called... Instead of generating, I can have a specific file to be copied depending on the command `npm run prod` or `npm run dev`